# open failed: EACCESS(Permission Denied) for downloading PDF and sharing them from Android12 and later

Tags: android, pdf-generation, android-permissions

I'm trying to download a pdf file from a URL in Android Webview. I use blob to get the data and create a file using javascript injection in webview. It works fine in samsung, pixel and xiaomi device but on Huawei device I getopen failed: EACCESS(Permission Denied) and no file is downloading, I read there is something about scoped storage but I cannot find correct permissions for pdf files. Can anyone please explain this to me. Thanks

```
 val fileName = context.getString(
      R.string.product_webview_file_name,
      DateUtils.getTodayDate(DATE_PATTERN_NO_SPACE)
    )
    val downloadPath = File(
      Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        .toString() + "/${fileName}"
    )
    val pdfAsBytes =
      Base64.decode(base64PDf.replaceFirst("^data:application/pdf;base64,".toRegex(), ""), 0)
    val os = FileOutputStream(downloadPath, false)
    os.write(pdfAsBytes)
    os.flush()
    if (downloadPath.exists()) {
      Toast.makeText(
        context,
        context.getText(R.string.product_webview_file_downloaded_label),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
      ).show()
      FileUtils.sharePdfFile(context = context, applicationId = applicationId, file = downloadPath)
    }
  }
```

I tried above code, so based on the comment, it works on all emulators for API 31,32,33,34 and tried with devices on samsung-33, xiaomi-32, but it shows above error on Huawei-32

Comment: You should mention Android versions of those devices. And compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your file name , it sounds weird but i got the same issue and only one of my devices , adding some strings to the name resolved the issue and i literaly doesn't know why and how !

Here the access is denied :

[image]

and then in my example i added `"_V1"` to the name and here is the result :

[image]

As you can see , adding some strings resolved the issue in this phone model ( samsung SM-N770F / Android 12 )

if someone has some explanation to this it would be nice

Comment: I used downloadManager to download pdf files instead, this solved the issue, seems like the issue was to download file in downloads folder in android, if I tried downloading the file to the app folder it downloaded but then the issue was to open the downloaded file. I just changed my entire solution to use download manager to download the file and user can view it from notification bar. Hope this helps